# `docker commit` fail while using `/sbin/init`

Tags: centos, docker

I know, I know. It is bad to want to have access to `servicectl` in a container, I know!

Now that this is behind us, I've got a problem. When I do something like this:

```
docker run -P --privileged --net=host --cidfile="/path/to/file.cid" -t -i --oom-kill-disable myimage /sbin/init
```

I do some stuff, wants to commit with this command :

```
docker commit -m 'Install This, configure that' 133c myimage
```

The command line waits, waits, waits. There is no write on disk, there is not much of an activity on the processors nor the RAM. And if I try `docker ps`, the terminal freezes too (I mean, even CTRL+C won't work).

But if I change the first command with

```
docker run -P --privileged --net=host --cidfile="/path/to/file.cid" -t -i --oom-kill-disable /bin/bash
```

I do the same modification, then commit and it works just fine (but I can't restart anything due to a D-Bus problem).

The container is on a CentOS 7.2 images, got the same problem on a CentOS Host and a Ubuntu Host.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **centos/systemd** base image, it contains the `systemd` rpm. Instead of the special `systemd-container` found in centos7 base image.

https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/

Then the cgroup volume is required

```
    docker run --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro centos:systemd
```